# How to set up spinner between SKScene transitions?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I have a very heavyweight scene that takes like 5 seconds to load.
I want some loading screen with a spinner to appear while it is waiting to load - what is elegant solution to that?

Should I make intermediate scene and show spinner on it while my scene loads?

Can I alloc and initWithSize scene in background thread?

Here is how I do it now:

```
MyScene *newScene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:1.0];
[self.view presentScene:newScene transition:transition];
```

But as soon as I press the button - game freezes for these 5 seconds and provides no feedback for player what is going on.

Tagging this as coco2d since it has very similar API and problems.

Comment: Wayne Hartman's answer is likely just what you need, but it occurs to me that it's possible  (and likely) that some of your 5 second delay comes from things that should happen in the background. If you're loading assets, for example, you don't need to block the UI thread. You could start your spinner, then load your content in the background, and call back to the main thread to load your new scene when it's done.

Comment: @dokkaebi this sound plausible. Can I do the alloc init of scene in background thread and then use it in main thread?

Comment: It depends what happens during that initialization. If it doesn't touch the view hierarchy, that should be okay. I haven't used sprite kit so you'll have to double check on how that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do things like this on a background thread.  What you can do is show your spinner first, then `dispatch_async` the actual transition:

```
// Write code for showing your spinner

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    MyScene *newScene = [[MyScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size];
    SKTransition *transition = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:1.0];
    [self.view presentScene:newScene transition:transition];
});
```

This will show your spinner and on the next run loop execute the transition.

Comment: Tangential, but `dispatch_async` is a bit prettier and more semantically correct when you don't care about the length of the delay.

Comment: @dokkaibi Completely agree!

Comment: But since my spinner is rotating on main thread, won't loading stuff on the same thread stop it from spinning?

Comment: @Dvole No, it will not.

Comment: This just causes a grey screen to flash for a second between my launch image and the first scene.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach:

In Interface Builder add `SKView`, Loading image, Large White Activity Indicator to `GameSceneViewController`:

[image]

Add outlets for added controls to `GameSceneViewController`:

```
@interface GameSceneViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SKView *skView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *loadingScreen;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

@end
```

In your `SKScene` add class method, which loads all assets for the scene:

```
+(void)loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:(AGAssetLoadCompletionHandler)handler {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        // Load the shared assets in the background.
        [self loadSceneAssets];

        if (!handler) {
            return;
        }

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Call the completion handler back on the main queue.
            handler();
        });
    });
}
```

where `AGAssetLoadCompletionHandler` is defined in `GameScene.h` as

```
/* Completion handler for callback after loading assets asynchronously. */
typedef void (^AGAssetLoadCompletionHandler)(void);
```

Same approach uses Apple in their [Sprite Kit Adventure Game](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/BuildingtheWorld/BuildingtheWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013140-CH3-SW1).

Finally, `GameSceneViewController`'s `viewWillAppear` method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.activityIndicator startAnimating];

    if (!self.skView.window) {
        [self.view addSubview:self.skView];
    }

    [GameScene loadSceneAssetsWithCompletionHandler:^{
         GameScene *scene = [[GameScene alloc] initWithSize:self.skView.bounds.size];
         scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeAspectFit;
         [self.skView presentScene:scene transition:[SKTransition crossFadeWithDuration:1]];
         [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            self.loadingScreen.alpha = 0.0f;
        } completion:NULL];

    }];
}
```